# unexpected token in soapUI Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

```
import com.eviware.sopeui.support.XmlHolder
def addreq=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["addEmployee"].testSteps["add"].getPropertyValue("Request")  
def name=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["addEmployee"].getPropertyValue("name")
def id=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["addEmployee"].getPropertyValue("id")
def dept=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["addEmployee"].getPropertyValue("dept")
def age=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["addEmployee"].getPropertyValue("age")
def xmlAdd=new XmlHolder(addReq)
xmlAdd.setNodeValue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:name",name)
xmlAdd.setNodeValue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:id",id)
xmlAdd.setNodeValue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:Department",dept)
xmlAdd.setNodeValue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:age"age)

def newAddXml=xmlAdd.getXml();
log.info newAddXml
```

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script42.groovy: 12: unexpected token: age @ line 12, column 48. ue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:age"age) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: age @ line 12, column 48. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:143) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:111) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:237) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:167) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:694) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:706) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:742) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:733) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Script42.groovy:12:48: unexpected token: age at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.argList(GroovyRecognizer.java:6991) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.methodCallArgs(GroovyRecognizer.java:11988) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.pathElement(GroovyRecognizer.java:11567) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.pathExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:11697) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.postfixExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:13410) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.unaryExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:13379) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.powerExpressionNotPlusMinus(GroovyRecognizer.java:13083) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.multiplicativeExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:13015) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.additiveExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12685) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.shiftExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:9921) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.relationalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12590) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.equalityExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12514) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.regexExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12462) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.andExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12430) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.exclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12398) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.inclusiveOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12366) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalAndExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12334) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.logicalOrExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:12302) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.conditionalExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:4956) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.assignmentExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:8122) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expression(GroovyRecognizer.java:10061) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatementNoCheck(GroovyRecognizer.java:8449) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatement(GroovyRecognizer.java:8995) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1278) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:760) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:134) ... 20 more 1 error

Comment: a small intro text wouldnt hurt. At least 2-3 sentences describing things...

Answer (score 0):

The error message states what's wrong and the line number, where it's
wrong:

```
unexpected token: age @ line 12, column 48. ue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:age"age) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: age @ line 12...
```

You missed a `,`:

```
xmlAdd.setNodeValue("//typ:addEmployee/typ:age"age)
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```